# I thought I had the worst but they had even worse?

Tags: sentence-construction, superlatives

How to describe a situation where you are far better off than others even though you didn't initially think it to be?

I want to complete the sentence. I thought I had the worst but they had even ____. How to fill in the blank?

Comment: I don't think there is a word meaning worse than worse, so you could try **I thought I had it bad but they had it worse**

Comment: I don't see any problem with 'worse' in the blank.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't think "worse" applies, or what choices you think there are?